# Can't import a Vagrant Box on Hyper-V

Tags: vagrant, hyper-v

I have created a Windows 10 vagrant box by exporting an existing VM from Hyper-V, adding a metadata.json file, deleting the snapshot folder, then creating a tar archive and gzipping the tar. I then add it to the box catalog by running

```
vagrant add ...
```

No problem so far.

If I try to up a new instance of the box, it fails with:

```
Script: import_vm.ps1
Error:

Failed to import a virtual machine.

Error Code: 32784
Cause: VM version is unsupported
```

To test the contents of the VM, I tried to manually import the VM from the export folder. Import works fine, so it's not that the disk files etc are corrupt.

Considering that I am importing on the same machine that I exported from, how is it possible that the version is not supported?

There seems to have previously been a bug in vagrant with these symptoms but it was fixed 2.5 years ago: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/7706.

I am running Windows 10 (1607 - OS Build 14393.2759), Hyper-V 10.0.14393.0 and Vagrant 2.2.4.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the late reply. As a first step, check the validity of your image. To do this see what happens if you import the VM directly through the Hyper-V Manager. This will rule out any issues with the version of vagrant you are using. I suspect Hyper-v manager will not be able to import the image either. The next thing I'd try is to upgrade your hyper-v version.

Comment: Hey Jeff - thanks for the response. I did try that and it imports perfectly if I do things manually. Subsequent to this post I have worked out that it seems vagrant only really works for windows from Hyper-V 8.2, and we are stuck on 8.0. Trying to get a system update from IT and will try again after that. And unfortunately due to needing to run Docker for Windows side by side, I can't switch to virtual box where I know everything will just work.

Comment: Also to note - Windows LTSB also causes this issue - need LTSC or later